# how to detect circle in image with openCV?

Tags: c, opencv

I want to detect circles in the image.this is the code i tried for detecting number of circles in this image:[image]

```
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //load image from directory
    IplImage* gray = cvLoadImage("comb.png",0);


   // IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    //covert to grayscale
    cvCvtColor(gray, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    // This is done so as to prevent a lot of false circles from being detected
   cvSmooth(gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 7, 7);

   IplImage* canny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(gray),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    //IplImage* rgbcanny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(gray),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
  cvCanny(gray, canny, 10, 20, 3);

    //detect circles
    CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, gray->width/10);

    if(circles->total>0)
    printf("circles found: %d\n",circles->total);
    else
    printf("circles not found");


  return 0;
}
```

but the following error occurs :-
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dst.data == dst0.data) in cvCvtColor, file /OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3811
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3811: error: (-215) dst.data == dst0.data in function cvCvtColor

please tell me what is wrong with the program.i am using ubuntu linux.

Comment: ***[good example here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html)***  Step by step.  Looks as if you are using C++?

Comment: The code snippet you show is just a few lines long, your problem description says line 3811 exception.  Is this referring to your code, or part of their library?  On what line does your code break?.  This looks like .lib (or .obj) incompatability with supporting .dll

Comment: have you tried to use a larger image with easier to find circles?

Comment: Have you checked if the input image is valid?
Don't use the ancient iplimage format with opencv2.4, read the new c++ examples

Answer (score 0):

You open `gray` as a gray image (`cvLoadImage("comb.png",0)`, with the "0" meaning "grayscale"). Then you try to convert this gray frame from RGB to Gray, and of course this cannot work since your image is already gray.

Simply try to comment out the following line:

```
//covert to grayscale
cvCvtColor(gray, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

---

By the way, you should use

```
IplImage* gray = cvLoadImage("comb.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

instead of

```
IplImage* gray = cvLoadImage("comb.png", 0);
```

That is clearer.